# Magento Checkout Continue button doesn't work in subdirectories

Tags: php, magento, checkout, subdirectory

I am using a magento 1.7.0.2. and have installed the ultimo theme. we have subdirectories set up and have had no problems with any other area of these.

When in a subdirectory and checkout. we enter our billing information as a guest and click 'continue' button. at this point nothing happens, the continue button disappears and there is no progression. it just sticks.

firebug came up with this error:

```
TypeError: descendants[k] is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

descendants[k].disabled = isDisabled;
```

opcheckout.js (line 81)

I just ran through it twice and for one subdirectory it worked fine(but didn't work before) and for another it hasn't worked at all.

Any help would be very welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just run into this problem today.

I changed l.81 in skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
from :

```
descendants[k].disabled = isDisabled;
```

to :

```
if(typeof(descendants[k]) != 'undefined') descendants[k].disabled = isDisabled;
```

seems to work...
I guess a better way would be to copy opcheckout.js in your own skin directory and make changes in this one.